# Storing a password in a dll, can refrence it on run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, passwords

I am looking to store a string field, a password, in a location that I can access within the code, but if you downloaded the code from a deployed place, you would not be able to access the password.  Web.config is available for all to see, or else I would just slide it in there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: while it's slightly more secure than storing it in the web.config, that's still a really insecure way to store a password.

Comment: You might change this question to ask how best to secure your application.  If you do that, please provide details such as your distribution method, likely environment it will be running in, and goals with regards to security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [encrypt values](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx) in web.config. It is a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Only slightly as the decryption key must be accessible by the application and therefore would be accessible by the user who runs the app.

Comment: @Chris Lively, yes I agree, but it is a web app that usually runs as a service account. Not all users that have access to the machine have access to the decryption key, only administrators.

Comment: Somehow I completely missed the part talking about asp.net. :/  In that case, this is about the best you can do. +1

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=055FF772-97FE-41B8-A58C-BF9C6593F25E

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you store a hash of the password?

On a more app design related note, once authenticated - why would you need to store the password locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this I would suggest you store a hash, even if it's retrived it would be useless (or at least less useful).

You have the FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile() method youc an use for generating MD5 and SHA1 hashes for comparing later.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at IsolatedStorage? Might be overkill but I think it's the surefire way to keep a secret from the user but available to the application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx